# Visual Studio code UI shows weird pattern

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've tried reboot, remove and install again but visual studio code shows me blank spaces with some weird "thing"

Can someone help me?

[image]

Comment: have you installed any extensions?

Comment: does it go away when you open a file?

Comment: have you disabled hardware acceleration (command line option)

Comment: thanks for your help!! Was problem of vpm network